# Count of Deleted Always Returns 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an MVVM application that allow user to mark records as deleted

```
public void DeleteRecord(object p)
{
    db.entry((MyEntityCast)p).state = EntityState.Deleted;
    ((DelegateCommand)ICommandSave).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Then I have a save `ICommandSave` with this canExecute:

```
public bool canExecuteSave(object param)
{
    decimal count = (from c in MyList
                      select c).Count(x=> db.Entry(x).State != EntityState.Unchanged);     
    return count !=0;
}
```

My problem is that count allways return `ListaTipoAsociado` less deleted ítems, it mean

if `MyList.count = 5`, and user mark for deletion 2 Ítems, this query return `0`, and `MyList.count` sets the new value as `3`.

My question is?

Why if the records are only `marked` for deletion (not deleted yet), I can't Access them in my query ?

There is an **EF** setting that i'm missing ?

**UPDATE 2:** MyList Definition

```
private ObservableCollection<MyEntity> _MyList;
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyList
{
    get { return _MyList; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _MyList, value); }
}

public constructor()
{
    var Q= from ta in db.MyEntity
           select ta;
    MyList= new ObservableCollection<MyEntity>(Q.ToList()); 
}
```

**UPDATE 3:** Class definition

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public MyEntity()
    {
        this.Childs = new HashSet<MyEntity2>();
    }

    public int IntTipoAsociado { get; set; }
    public string StrDescripcionTipoAsociado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MyEntity2> MyEntity2{ get; set; }
}
```

And the context:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("name=MyEntities")
    {
    }

    public MyEntities(string connectioString)
        : base(connectioString)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyEntity2> MyEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are your entities in MyList atteched to a context?
What will be a result of MyList.Select(x=>db.Entry(x).State) query? Maybe it'll shine a little light on your problem.

Comment: Tks a lot, MyList already attached to a context. I'm going to try your query suggest.

Comment: The query you suggest me return only 3 ítems.

Comment: That's interesting.. I'll have to play with it myself later.

Comment: What is `MyList` and where does it come from?

Comment: @Slauma MyList is an ObservabelCollection and it comes from a  query. Pleas see Updte 2

Comment: OK, I see. But I don't understand your statement: "*if MyList.count = 5, and user mark for deletion 2 Ítems, this query return 0, and MyList.count sets the new value as 3.*" Which query returns 0? The expression in `Count(...)` filters for `!= Unchanged`. Returning 0 would mean that everything is in state `Unchanged`. Do you mean that? And where does the new value 3 come from? Do you run the query in `constructor` again and then `MyList` has only 3 elements instead of 5? Could try to explain it more precisely?

Comment: @Slauma Thas the exact point, if 2 records of 5 are marked as ``Deleted`` the query must return 2, it allways return 0, And my list has now 3  elements. The only action performed was Mark those 2 elements state with ``EntityState.Deleted``

Comment: I've tried to reproduce that, but it works for me. Are you using `DbSet<MyEntity>.Local` somewhere? The behaviour you describe has an explanation if `MyList` would be the `Local` collection. But with the instantiation of `MyList` in your code snippet I have no idea how this could happen...